# Why? QObject destruction doesn't suffer with, passing CRT Objects Across DLL Boundaries

Tags: c++, dll

As per the c++ standard, object created by a module (dll) must be deleted in same module, and if we pass an object across the dll boundaries it corrupt the heap. (as explain in following link [Potential Errors Passing CRT Objects Across DLL Boundaries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235460.aspx)

Now in my application, if i create parent object (QObject or subclass of it) and few child objects(child means QObject tree), finally at the end of application i delete a parent object (in exe) and dll will delete all child objects.

**So Why it does't have any problem?**

Comment: The C++ standard has no notion of "DLLs" or "modules".

Comment: QT modules are built with /MD by default, the compiler option that avoids the problem.  Do beware that the linked article is outdated, the Microsoft CRT no longer uses a private heap since VS2012 and now allocates from the default process heap.